# Difference between setting `scrollTop` directly and setting it with `$.animate`

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, jquery-animate, mousewheel

In a `mousewheel` event handler, I changed a statement that updates a element's `scrollTop`:

```
-        list.scrollTop(newScrollTop);
+        list.animate({
+            scrollTop: newScrollTop
+        }, 80);
```

I added this `animate` to make the list scroll smoothly, and it works on Chrome like the original statement.

But on IE7, the `animate` version make the scroll unusable, when I scroll, the list move only some 10px on the screen.

What could possibly be the reason of this?

Comment: It moves 10px, and then stops?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Not exactly. It's just a little movement. The result of this effect is that a IE7 user has to scroll a lot to make the `list` move a little.

Comment: It could be that the `animate` function chokes in IE7. That wouldn't surprise me since IE7's JavaScript performance is very slow compared to modern browsers.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I guess it should be about `scrollTop`, because we have been using `animate` on other elements and they all works.

Comment: How much does each `newScrollTop` invocation scroll the contents? Maybe you just need a larger value for IE7.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yes, I've tried this and it works, I just don't know why.